# Java Export SQL Query to CSV leading zeroes and Number truncation

Tags: java, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I am exporting results of an SQL query where all the fields are varchar strings.  Fields such as serial numbers which may or may not contain letters, building numbers, and room numbers that should retain all their characters in order to be of any use in the report.  For example, Serial number **0129306201100910** gets truncated to **1.29306E+14** making it useless data. Here is the code I am using in order to do the actual writing of the export.  Any suggestions on how to modify this in order to keep leading zeroes and stop the scientific notation truncation? Thanks in advance.

```
wr.write("\"Inventory_No\",\"Building_No\",\"Actual_Building\",\"Room_No\",\"Actual_Room\",\"CDDEPT\",\"Location\",\"Actual_Location\",\"Normalized_MFG\""
                        + ",\"Manufacturer\",\"Normalized_Model\",\"Model\",\"Serial Code\""
                        + ",\"Cost\",\"Account_No\",\"Active\"");
                wr.newLine();
                int count = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    count += 1;
                    if (count % 1000 == 0) {
                        wr.flush();
                        response.flushBuffer();
                    }
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Inventory_No") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Building_No") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Actual_Building") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Room_No") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Actual_Room") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("CDDEPT") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Location") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Actual_Location") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Normalized_MFG") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Manufacturer_Name") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Normalized_Model") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Name") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Serial_Code") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Cost") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Account_No") + "\",");
                    wr.write("\"" + rs.getString("Active") + "\",");
                    wr.newLine();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your csv writer formats the cell as "Text" which will write it as text disabling scientific notation.

In case you double click on your cell you should be seeing the full value with your current code.

Comment: This is what I have for setting up the csv `writer.response.setContentType("text/csv");
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=inventory.csv");
                final BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()));`

Comment: oh in this case you are not setting the format for the column hence the default format is being picked up by the csv

Comment: can you use excel library like Apache POI or OpenCSV ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a feature to make its own CSV file. Like this:

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.text' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM test_table;
```

So you can set, with its own SQL functions, the appropriate values ​​to be exported to CSV. And download this file on the server.

The documentation for this operation, is available at [SELECT MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a library such as [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/)